# Yaw value of 200 when roll and pitch are fine using madgwick filter arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors, rocket

my yaw value seems to be offset right from the start and all values seem to be extremely slow to respond to any movement - before using the filter each sensors values responded adequately.

I have tried alternating the axes of the magnetometer with no luck. I am quite new to coding and to microcontrollers so i am not too knowledgeable. I wanted to get a working euler angle programme before going onto use quaternions to log flight data for my model rocket.

```
 `#include "Arduino_BMI270_BMM150.h"
 #include <MadgwickAHRS.h>

float gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az, mx, my, mz;
float roll, pitch, yaw;
Madgwick filter;

unsigned long lastMagUpdate = 0; //can hold large positive integers 
const int magUpdateRate = 100; // Magnetometer update rate in milliseconds (10 Hz)

void setup() {
 // Existing setup code...
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial) 
Serial.println("Started");

 if (!IMU.begin()) {
  Serial.println("IMU initialization unsuccessful");
  while (1);
 }
  Serial.print("Accelerometer sample rate = ");
  Serial.print(IMU.accelerationSampleRate());
  Serial.println(" Hz");

  Serial.print("Gyroscope sample rate = ");
  Serial.println(IMU.gyroscopeSampleRate());
  Serial.println(" Hz");

  Serial.println("Magnetometer sample rate = ");
  Serial.print(IMU.magneticFieldSampleRate());
  Serial.println(" Hz");

  filter.begin(IMU.accelerationSampleRate());
  }

  void loop() {
    if (IMU.gyroscopeAvailable() && IMU.accelerationAvailable()) {
      float Rgx, Rgy, Rgz;
      float Rax, Ray, Raz;
      IMU.readGyroscope(Rgx, Rgy, Rgz);
      IMU.readAcceleration(Rax, Ray, Raz);

      convertToRadians(Rgx,Rgy,Rgz); 
      convertToM_s2(Rax,Ray,Raz);




     // Update the magnetometer readings less frequently
   if (millis() - lastMagUpdate >= magUpdateRate) {    //millis returns time since program began
  if (IMU.magneticFieldAvailable()) {            
    lastMagUpdate = millis();
  }
    }


filter.update(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az, mx, my, mz);

// Convert to Euler angles
roll = filter.getRoll();
pitch = filter.getPitch();
yaw = filter.getYaw();

// Output the data
Serial.print("Roll: "); Serial.print(roll); Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print("Pitch: "); Serial.print(pitch);        Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print("Yaw: "); Serial.print(yaw);          Serial.println();
    }
    }
     void convertToRadians(float Rgx, float Rgy, float Rgz) {
     gx = Rgx*PI/180; gy= Rgy*PI/180; gz = Rgz*PI/180;
    }
   void convertToM_s2(float Rax, float Ray, float Raz) {
    ax =Rax*9.81; ay=Ray*9.81; az =Raz*9.81;
   }
 `
```